# Como hacer para establecer un placeholder y que no desaparezca

Tags: html, angular, formularios

En mi aplicación tengo el siguiente select:

```
<select class="form-select text-secondary" name="date_type" #date_type="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dateType" required>
    <option class="text-secondary" value="undefined" disabled selected>Tipo de cita</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of typeDates" [ngValue]="type.id" >{{type.name}} {{type.duration}}</option>
</select>
```

la cuestión es que si abro el evento en un modal para ver la información , desaparece el placeholder del select. O incluso una vez que envío el formulario el placeholder queda vacío

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Con placeholder te refieres al texto: Tipo de cita

Comment: si. tengo entendido que en los select no existe un placeholder como tal, en su lugar debe seleccionarse por defecto una opción y luego ponerla en disable. Pero cuando cargo la pagina se muestra, pero como dije antes, cuando envio el formulario se queda en blanco, he probado con refrescando el formulario, pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: Entiendo, lo que te puedo aconsejar es que hagas esa manipulación en tu array typeDates. Algo como this.typeDates.unshift({ value: null, label: 'Tipo de cita' }); Entonces tu ngFor se encarga de mostrar el 'placeholder'. Podrías compartir tu código si tienes dudas

Comment: Cambia `value="undefined"` por  `value="" `

Comment: Gracias Yussef. Si esto ya lo intente y no funciona

Comment: Muestra la estructura de array de tu typeDates